# Force window to stop loading/close in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to test a series of links. Most work just fine, but some take particularly long to load. All I need to do is verify that a window with the proper title appears, which I am able to do just fine. The problem is when I try to close a page that is still loading, I get a timeout error -- the close method can't complete while Watir webdriver is still waiting for the page to load. I've looked around a lot but have been unable to find a fix for this other than messing with the timeout settings to be however long it takes the webpage to load. Is there any way to force the window to close once I've verfied that the title I'm looking for exists on that window? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, these aren't watir-webdriver solutions, but you could use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) to retrieve the page titles.  That way, you wouldn't even need a browser.  Some examples:

**Nokogiri**

```
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'

URLS = ["http://www.example.org/", "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"]

URLS.each do |url|
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}"))  
  puts page.css('title')
end

#=> <title>Example Domain</title>
#=> <title>IANA - IANA-managed Reserved Domains</title>
```

**Mechanize**

```
require 'mechanize'

URLS = ["http://www.example.org/", "http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved"]

URLS.each do |url|
  agent = Mechanize.new
  puts agent.get("#{url}").title 
end

# => Example Domain
# => IANA - IANA-managed Reserved Domains
```